# What does 'ADD file ... in /' in docker base images at dockerhub.com

Tags: docker

I'm trying to find a suitable base image at [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/), and I'm not sure whether the image with the tag `Nvidia/cuda:11.1.1-base-ubuntu20.04` contains the `ubuntu20.04` environment or not. If the answer is yes, why don't I see anything about `ubuntu` in its `Dockerfile`. And what's the use of `ADD file ...`
[image]

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Don't post text as images. Read the docker file reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about this cuda image: https://hub.docker.com/layers/nvidia/cuda/11.1.1-devel-ubuntu20.04/images/sha256-2b02390a7988c592578466083a1353fa8bb815167f05c44282014c60044352c6?context=explore

You cannot see references to parent image, because `FROM` is not layer. In the Dockerhub you can see layers only.

The `FROM` command includes all layers from base image. Those first layers you are thinking about are included from the Ubuntu image.

You can find template for `Dockerfile` here: https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/blob/master/templates/ubuntu/base-dockerfile.j2

Then you can see layers 6(LABEL) and 7(RUN) in dockerhub corresponding to the template layers. All above layers are included from base(parent) image

```
LABEL maintainer "NVIDIA CORPORATION <cudatools@nvidia.com>"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
{% if cuda.os.version in ["18.04", "20.04"] %}
    gnupg2 curl ca-certificates && \
    curl -fsSL {{ cuda.repo_url }}/7fa2af80.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb {{ cuda.repo_url }} /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list && \
    {% if cuda.use_ml_repo %}
    echo "deb {{ cuda.ml_repo_url }} /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list && \
    {% endif %}
    apt-get purge --autoremove -y curl \
{% elif cuda.os.version == "16.04" %}
    ca-certificates apt-transport-https gnupg-curl && \
    NVIDIA_GPGKEY_SUM=d1be581509378368edeec8c1eb2958702feedf3bc3d17011adbf24efacce4ab5 && \
    NVIDIA_GPGKEY_FPR=ae09fe4bbd223a84b2ccfce3f60f4b3d7fa2af80 && \
    apt-key adv --fetch-keys {{ cuda.repo_url }}/7fa2af80.pub && \
    apt-key adv --export --no-emit-version -a $NVIDIA_GPGKEY_FPR | tail -n +5 > cudasign.pub && \
    echo "$NVIDIA_GPGKEY_SUM  cudasign.pub" | sha256sum -c --strict - && rm cudasign.pub && \
    echo "deb {{ cuda.repo_url }} /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list && \
    {% if cuda.use_ml_repo %}
    echo "deb {{ cuda.ml_repo_url }} /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list && \
    {% endif %}
    apt-get purge --auto-remove -y gnupg-curl \
{% endif %}
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. you can try to use google to find the parent: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:hub.docker.com+4f15c4475fbafb3fe335e415e3ea1ac416c34af911fcdfe273c5759438aa8eb4